# Object origin is being set to wherever the 3d cursor is even if i move it. How do i fix it?

Tags: modeling

the object origin is currently at the location of the 3d cursor. Right clicking moves the 3d cursor (i have left click to select on) but it also moves the object origin/rotation point. doing ctrl alt shft c and selecting any of the option does nothing. How do i set things so that the object origin just stays in the middle of the object.

Comment: Sounds like you have messed up your keymap configuration. Have you tried to reset to Factory defaults? File -> Load Factory Settings.

Comment: are you sure it is your object origin that is moved? Is there an orange Dot where your Cursor is?

Comment: Object origin can't be moved that easily, likely you move 3D cursor and pivot point is moved with it which is when pivot is set to 3D cursor

Answer (score 2):

Your Transform Pivot is just set to Pivot Cursor. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> to go back to Median Transform. The Shortcut for Cursor Pivot is by the way <kbd>.</kbd> so you might accidently clicked it. This answer only applies if you are a beginner and you don't know what the object origin is. Your question doesn't provides an image so I just assumed it

Comment: and i am a begginer\

Comment: would you mind verify my answer as correct?

Answer (score 0):

If  you look on the footer of the 3D view, you have view, select, add and mesh menus then mode and view selections and then the origin settings, which need to be changed from 3d cursor to median centre.